# Mootools Lightbox with Img Slider

Tags: events, mootools, lightbox, duration

I use the Mootools Mediabox for my Site.
This one mediaboxAdvanced v1.4.6.

Now i looking for a solution that the image change automatically afer 5 Sec.
In the code i found thie

```
{id:"mbNextLink",href:"#"})).addEvent("click",R)
```

But didn't found a solution with duration and addEvent.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by looking at the code you should be able to do it by extending the mediaboxAdvanced code.

Just look for `Mediabox = {` in the code and add a function after that. For example:

```
showNext: function(){
    next();
},
```

then you should be able to use `setInterval` for example to make it automatically advance after 5 seconds.